# AngularJS - Unknown route length

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I would like to create an application that allows unlimited nesting of documents.

Each subdocument is represented in the url : `/document/sub1/sub2`

How do I configure a route with `$routeProvider` that has a unknown length?

Is there a way to count the level of nesting in the url in a clean way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that you can group a route paramter:

> path can contain named groups starting with a colon and ending with a star: e.g.:name*. All characters are eagerly stored in $routeParams under the given name when the route matches.
>
> For example, routes like /color/:color/largecode/:largecode*/edit will match /color/brown/largecode/code/with/slashes/edit and extract: